# Keep pair of row data in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a problem to eliminate the row data based on pair of two column data. I have a hundred csv data.
My data looks like this:

```
ID  Annotation
A   first
A   last
B   first
C   first
C   last
D   last
E   first
E   last
```

I want to eliminate row in ID column which is only one appeared.

I used this code:

```
files = glob.glob("Data-*.csv") 
for f in files:
    df = pd.read_csv(f)
    df = df[df.groupby('ID').ID.transform(len) > 1]
    df.to_csv('New' + ' ' + f)
```

and:

```
df[df.duplicated('ID',keep=False)]
```

and

```
df1['count'] = df1.groupby(['ID']).transform(pd.Series.count) 
df1 = df1[df1['count']>1]
df1
```

I got an error:

```
Wrong number of items passed 4, placement implies 1
```

but the only one data still appeared. My expected result looks like this:

```
ID  Annotation
A   first
A   last
C   first
C   last
E   first
E   last
```

EDITED

For the test data, These codes are working very well. However, for my original data, it doesn't. This is one of the original [Data](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1X4G-5pqTIXHb4h5WUBeFEoWRdnAux2bv)

Comment: `df[df.duplicated('ID',keep=False)]` it is just like the previous question except instead of taking 2 cols, we are now taking one

Comment: this code 'df[df.duplicated('ID',keep=False)]' still not working

Comment: working for the test data, you have to check if the test data is similar to the original dataset

Comment: maybe you are right. I don't know why for my original dataset is not working, even I try to open and analyze just one file.

Comment: df['count']  = df.groupby(['ID']).transform(pd.Series.count)  then filter df[df['count']>1]

Comment: @tawab_shakeel for the test data is good way. however, I still got an error for my original data. I got `Wrong number of items passed 4, placement implies 1`

Comment: if you can give complete data then any one can check the issue

Comment: @tawab_shakeel this is my data https://drive.google.com/open?id=1X4G-5pqTIXHb4h5WUBeFEoWRdnAux2bv and The question was edited.

Comment: @Arief which col is an ID

Comment: @tawab_shakeel Mac col.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195438/discussion-between-tawab-shakeel-and-arief).